# AWS SAM Local RuntimeError in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sam

I am trying to run a basic lambda function (using article blueprint in AWS serverless project creator in Eclipse). When I try to run the project as AWS SAM Local, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bliu4/.local/bin/sam", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/Users/bliu4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bliu4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 676, in main
    _verify_python3_env()
  File "/Users/bliu4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/_unicodefun.py", line 118, in _verify_python3_env
    'for mitigation steps.' + extra)
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment.  Consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/for mitigation steps.
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? Any idea how to change the python version sam is calling? Thanks.